# Why is my Angular scope variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I have a quotes array which contains 6 quotes.
Next I have a `getRandomNum` function which returns a number between 0 and 6.

To be used in my `chooseQuote` function:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DashCtrl as dash">

    <div class="quotes" title="Quotes">
        <p>{{dash.chooseQuote(dash.num)}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

**Code in my Dash Controller:**

```
var vm = this;
var num = 0;

var quotes = [
    {
        quote: "Money won't create success, the freedom to make it will.",
        author: "Nelson Mandela"
    },
    // etc ...
];

function getRandomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

num = getRandomNum(0, 5);

vm.chooseQuote = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    return quotes[i]["quote"];
}

console.log(num);
console.log(vm.chooseQuote(num));
```

Now checking the console I'm getting num is undefined as well as can't get 'quote' of undefined. This happens inside of my `chooseQuote` function the 2nd time it's called.

**First console.log:**
[image]

Works fine, so does the next console.log which prints the correct quote, however on the last console.log, 2nd time it goes into my `chooseQuote` function I get i/num is undefined:

[image]

**Do you see where I'm going wrong here?**

Comment: You haven't put dash.num onto your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num` is defined as a private controller variable in the code you've provided. It looks as though `vm` is what you're using to reference the $scope of the controller, so you'll need to make `num` a property of `vm` so it's exposed to the view.

```
vm.num = 0;

...

vm.num = getRandomNum(0, 5);

...

console.log(vm.num);
console.log(vm.chooseQuote(vm.num));
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before... but I was still getting num was undefined, but it was probably due to an older version of my num var in my console.logs...